# Probability- Cumulative distribution function of rooks on chess board

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, random-functions, chessboard

There is a chess board that is 8*8 grid. A rook is attacking another piece if they are on the same row or column.

1.Eight rooks are being randomly set up on an empty chess board. What is expected value of the number of the "threatened" rooks?

2. An unlimited number of rooks are being randomly organized until there is a rook who is being "threatened". What is the cumulative distribution function of the number of rooks that were placed on the board?

I have  problem solving the second part... I am not sure how to solve it and what is the support of this random variable... Which kind is the random variable? Is there something that is suitable even? 
And can I say that from (including) the 9th rook the probability is 1?

Comment: Tackling the easiest problem first, with a 9th rook, the probability is 1, as there is no way to set up 9 rooks so they can't attack each other.

Comment: In your question, is it possible for two rooks to be on the same square?

Comment: It may be easier to solve the complementary problem: If $n$ rooks are placed at random on the board, what is the probability that no two are on the same row or column?